# How to get complete system log from android

Tags: android, logging, logcat, android-logcat

I want get complete system log. Currently, I'm using below code to get system log

```
try {
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -v threadtime *:I");
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lineList.add(line);
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        Log.e(e.toString());
    }
```

I'm able to get system log successfully using above code. It gives only last 30 min log. But, I want complete system log from my application launch. Is it possible to write system log to our private file?

Comment: You have to remove the -d option because it actually "Dumps the log to the screen and exits." If you want it to keep printing the log , logcat must not be terminated. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: Is it possible to write system log continuously into private file?

Comment: Yes, you just need to write every line that you read on a file on the disk.

Comment: Do you know how to stop reading from logcat?

Answer (score 1):

To write continuously to a file, try this:

```
... exec( "logcat -f cachedirectory/logfile.txt -v threadtime" );
```

See the -f option in http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html.